# counting length and number of substrings

Tags: r

I am trying to count the number of groups of consecutive 1's in the following string:

```
"NA-111111111-1111111-1-1-11-111-1-1-11-111-111-1-111-11-1-11-1111-111111111111-1111111-1-1-1-11-11-1-1-1-11-11111-1-1-11-11111111-1-1-1-1-1111-1-1-1-111-1-1-1-11111-1-11111-1-1-1-1-11111-1111111-1-1-111-1-1-1111-1-1-111-111-1-1-11-11-111-11111-111-1-1111-1-1-1-111111111-1-1-1-1-1-11-1-111-1-11111-1-1-11-1-1-1-1-111111-1-1-11-1-111111-1-1111-11-1-11-1-1-11111-1-111111-11-111-111-1-11-11-1-1-1-11-1-1-1-11111-1-11111-1-111-1-11-111111-1-11-1-1-11-1111-11111-1111111-1-1-1-1111-1-1-11-111-1111-11-1-11-1-111-1111111111-1-1-11111-1-1-1-111-11111-1-1-1-1111-1-1-1-1-1111-1-1-111111111-11111-1111111-1-1-111-11-1-11111-1-1-1111111111-1-1-1-1-1-11111-11-11-1111-1-11-1-1-11111-1-1-1-1-1-11-1-11111111-1-1111-1-1111-1"
```

Can someone suggest a method for doing this? I tried to split the string and failed when trying to count segments.

example: "NA-111111111-1111111-1-1-11-111-1-1-11"

```
string    quantity
11111111  1 
111111    1
1         2
11        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using `gregexpr`:

```
s <- "NA-111111111-1111111-1-1-11-111-1-1-11"
match <- gregexpr("1+", s)
pattern <- sapply(attr(match[[1]], "match.length"), 
                  function(i) paste0(rep("1", i), collapse = ""))
data.frame(pattern) %>% group_by(pattern) %>% 
          mutate(quantity = n()) %>% unique()

Source: local data frame [5 x 2]
Groups: pattern [5]

    pattern quantity
     (fctr)    (int)
1 111111111        1
2   1111111        1
3         1        4
4        11        2
5       111        1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example string and output don't seem to match...

But I think this is what you what:

```
string <- "NA-111111111-1111111-1-1-11-111-1-1-11"
table(strsplit(string, "-"))
#   1        11       111   1111111 111111111        NA 
#   4         2         1         1         1         1
```

***EDIT***
If you actually want to remove the "-1", this matches your example output:

```
table(strsplit(string, "-1"))

#                1       11   111111 11111111       NA 
#       4        2        1        1        1        1
```

The blanks occur when multiple "-1" were removed in a row.

Comment: My apologies, my example was a bit unclear, the two values are (1) and (-1)

Comment: I see, but then you can just change the pattern to "-1" instead of "-", or is that also not what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option with `str_extract` and `table`

```
library(stringr)
as.data.frame(table(str_extract_all(s, '[^-]+')[[1]], exclude="NA"))
#       Var1 Freq
#1         1    4
#2        11    2
#3       111    1
#4   1111111    1
#5 111111111    1
```

#### data

```
s <- "NA-111111111-1111111-1-1-11-111-1-1-11"
```